# como contar los usuarios activos con javascript?

Tags: nodejs, express

Deseo poder contar los usuarios que esten conectados en una pagina web desde el servidor, esta programado con nodejs

Comment: puedes ser mas especifico, indicando que haz intentado, que te ha fallado, con que gestor de bases de datos trabajas? todo eso es necesario de otro modo nadie sabe exactamente que ocupas

Comment: trabajo con mysql, nodejs, para la conexion utilizo knexjs y la verdad no he intentado nada, ya que no tengo la menor idea de co mo pueda hacerlo con javascript

Comment: Hola Fabian. cuando haces referencia a estar conectados es saber la cantidad de usuarios que tienen activa una sesión? o que solo ingresan a tu página web a revisar contenido?

Comment: Hola Miguel. Me refiero a los que ingresar y que en ese momentos estan activos.